# Wordpress - Trying to display date from custom form two different ways

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create an events page in Wordpress. I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to generate my forms. I would like to style the month and year differently from the day in the listing section. However, I don't want to make the user have to input the same date twice in the back-end just for this. Is there a way to display the content from the one form in two different calibrations on the front-end? For example, can I display it once as month and year then once again as just the day? Is there any other workaround? Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my custom form code:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_5fec83c0a2f7b',
    'title' => 'Event Particulars',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5fec83ca0dc8b',
            'label' => 'Date of event',
            'name' => 'date_of_event',
            'type' => 'date_picker',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'field' => 'field_5fec84a00dc8c',
                        'operator' => '!=empty',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'display_format' => 'Y F j',
            'return_format' => 'Y F j',
            'first_day' => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5fec84a00dc8c',
            'label' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'page_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'front_page',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the value of the date field, create a date object and then format that date object as you prefer:

```
// Load field value.
$date_string = get_field('date_of_event');

// Create DateTime object from value.
// Here you must use the format that you specified as the "return format" of the date field in ACF.
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F j', $date_string);

// Now you can use the date object to print the date in different formats:
echo $date->format('M Y');
echo $date->format('j M Y');
```

Have a look at the "Modifiy value" section of the docs:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/